# JavaScript: typeof attr.name returns undefined

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get all possible data-* attributes from every tag on my page.

```
var el = document.body.querySelectorAll("*");
for(i=0;i<el.length;i++){
  var datas = [].filter.call(el[i].attributes, function(at) { return /^data-/.test(at.name); });
}
```

now datas variable contains attribute objects and I want to search datas.name for specific value, in my case I'm searching for "data-val". But
    typeof datas.name
returns undefined. Any clue what to do? Pure JavaScript please. Thanx!

**update**

I could go with the following solution:

```
var el = document.body.querySelectorAll("*");
for(i=0;i<el.length;i++){
  var datas = [].filter.call(el[i].attributes, function(at) { return /^data-/.test(at.name); });
  for(var k=0;k<datas.length;k++){
    nodes.push(datas[k].name.replace(/^data-/,""));
  }
  for(var l=0;l<nodes.length;l++) {
    if(nodes.search("val")>0){
      ...do my code here...
    }
  }
}
```

but is there a more elegant way to do that?

Comment: I don't know if it would be faster, but for new browser you could think over using `Object.keys(el[i].dataset)`. ([MDN: dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.dataset))

Comment: Why don't you just use that condition for your `.filter()` callback? `return /^data-val$/.test(at.name);`

Comment: ...frankly, I can't tell what your solution was supposed to do. You're just pushing the names, minus the `data-` part, of all the data attributes into a `nodes` Array that doesn't exist, and then iterating `nodes`, and for each iteration, doing a `.search()` *(which isn't a native method)* on the entire `nodes` collection.

Comment: cookie monster, my bad. `nodes` is defined earlier, and instead of `.search()` I'm using `.indexOf()`. For some reason I need to get all data attributes first and then perform a search in it for a specific value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var el = document.body.querySelectorAll("*"),
    i = 0,
    j = 0,
    len = el.length;

for (; i < len; i++) {
    var x = el[i].attributes,
        len2 = x.length;
    for (; j < len2; j++) {
        if (x[j].name === "data-val") console.log("data-val present");
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MsSht/1/